# Can't get Custom Object ParentID for Attachment save

Tags: apex, visualforce, ajax

I'm uploading an attachment via "sforce" following the example here:

[Upload attachment in VisualForce without reloading the whole page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88933/upload-attachment-in-visualforce-without-reloading-the-whole-page)

However I'm having problems getting a value for ParentId. I first tried to instantiate a new custom object in my controller constructor like this:

```
public Custom_object__c attachmentParent {get; set;}

public MyControllerConstructor() {
        attachmentParent = new Custom_object__c(Name="temp");
        insert attachmentParent;
    }
```

But when I'm in the visualforce page and I try to set the parentId field to {!attachmentParent.Id} it comes back blank. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: A record won't have an ID until it's inserted to the database. You can't add an Attachment to a record that hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: Right, and I realize that, but even when I add "Insert attachmentParent" into my constructor I still don't get the Id in the page. I think it might be because insertions (DML) are not allowed in the constructor. So I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform any `DML` in the constructor. If you really want to create a new parent on the fly for this page, use the `action` attribute on your `page` tag.

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" action="{!createParent}">
```

Then in your controller:

```
public PageReference createParent()
{
    attachmentParent = new Custom_object__c(Name="temp");
    insert attachmentParent;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I've heard this approach will not pass the security review. I'm trying to figure out if there is a better approach to what I'm doing and end up with something that will pass security review. My end goal is to be able to save attachments to objects using sforce.connection.create but I need to know the "approved" way to get a parentId to pass in

Comment: You are right, but I don't think dummy parent records for your attachment records will anyway. Can you explain in more detail why you need a dummy record?

Comment: Is there an actual parent already in the database and you just need to find it?

Comment: It's not a dummy attachment record, I'm pulling the file object from an input field and using readAsBinaryString (in the link I posted for the example). For every file the user uploads I want to save it as an attachment to a new record in Custom_object__c. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Dummy parents. You could create one via `RemoteAction` instead. @asol

Comment: I understand, you're calling it a dummy record because normally people would be saving attachments to pre-existing records. In my case this attachment is only temporary - I need to save it temporarily in SF and then I'm POSTing it to a different service. Is there a better way of saving attachments temporarily?

Comment: What kind of attachment? Again remoting is more likely to pass review.

Comment: Can we talk in a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40416/discussion-between-asolberg-and-adrian-larson).