# AJAX Toolkit logs error "NetworkError: A network error occurred."

Tags: visualforce, attachment, upload, ajax-toolkit

I'm using the Ajax Toolkit to upload files on a VF page, like described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88933/upload-attachment-in-visualforce-without-reloading-the-whole-page).
The Upload works fine, the file is available and not damaged. But the response is not coming back properly.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    
    function addAttachment(input, parentId){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var attachFile = $("#"+input)[0].files[0];
        
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var attachment = new sforce.SObject('Attachment');  
            attachment.IsPrivate = false;  
            attachment.Name = attachFile.name;
            attachment.Description = attachFile.name;
            attachment.ContentType = attachFile.type;
            attachment.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();
            attachment.ParentId = parentId;

            console.log('lets go');
            var response = sforce.connection.create([attachment]);  

            if(response[0].getBoolean("success")){  
                console.log('file added successfully');
            }
            else{
                console.log('error occured');
            }
        };
        
        reader.readAsBinaryString(attachFile);
        
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The response logs above (if/else) are not outputted, but the only logs I get are:

> lets go
>
> NetworkError: A network error occurred.

The error is thrown in row 595 in the connection.js What actually tells me nothing.

[image]

I feel like I'm staying close to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_vf_sample.htm). Any Idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this occurred is because the apex:commandButton causes a form POST when you do not use a reRender target and you do not cancel the POST. When a POST occurs, all pending network transactions are cancelled.

There are actually three acceptable ways to fix this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Upload" 
    onclick="addAttachment('fileInput', '{!parent.Id}');" 
    rerender="none" /> <!-- "none" can be any value at all -->
```

Or:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Upload" 
    onclick="addAttachment('fileInput', '{!parent.Id}');" 
    oncomplete="" /> <!-- oncomplete makes this an AJAX call -->
```

Or:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Upload" 
onclick="addAttachment('fileInput', '{!parent.Id}'); return false;" />
<!-- return false stops the default POST -->
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you explain the difference between returning false on the button vs. returning false in the method? shouldn't it be the same? `rerender=""` didn't work, but `rerender="nothing"` did.

Comment: Btw you might also add `oncomplete=""` to your answer, it did the same thing.

Comment: @Basti you need to return the false value to the underlying handler. You could also write `onclick="return addAttachment(...)`, but simply returning false from the function itself isn't enough. I'll go ahead and make an edit, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the rerender attribute to my commandButton, problem solved.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Upload" onclick="addAttachment('fileInput', '{!parent.Id}');" rerender="form" />
```